# How to set custom Firebase Security?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I haven't used Firebase Authentication. All my data is used from the database. The storage and database rules are set to public. Finally, How do i set it so that only admins can write/delete data?

Here are 2 pictures of the database :

1.Tree View With User Details
[image: Tree view with user without admin]

2.Tree View With Admin Details
[image: Tree view with admin without user]

Comment: If you're not using Firebase Authentication, then the Firebase Database has no way of knowing what user is making a change.

Comment: Ah...yes. I thought so, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Firebase Auth. Sign up an account for the Admin users, then add the admin users user ID as the only one that can read/write.

```
 "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": auth.uid == 'ansiodfnio3n20nas0dnf0asn',
        ".write": auth.uid == 'ansiodfnio3n20nas0dnf0asn'",
      },
```

Without setting up firebase admin, there isn't much you can do except totally lock it down and using a backend server to access the DB.

Comment: Understood, thanks for the input. I assume it's the same for firebase storage.

Comment: Basically, yes, it is.